# pyodbc encrypt username and password

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode, pyodbc-4.0.34, Python 3.10.7.

Code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/data-exploration/python-dataframe-pandas?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
server = 'servername' 
database = 'AdventureWorks' 
username = 'yourusername' 
password = 'databasename'  
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
# select 26 rows from SQL table to insert in dataframe.
query = "SELECT [CountryRegionCode], [Name] FROM Person.CountryRegion;"
df = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)
print(df.head(26))
```

I am saving my code to GitHub however I do not want to save usernames and passwords. What is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: define shell/terminal environment variables and extract these in the code, or use command line arguments

Comment: Do you mind giving an example of a command line argument? Is the password stored in my local machine somewhere?

Comment: Have you performed a search for `command line argument python`? Many sites already that tells you how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use command line argument to give the argument to python when you run the file in the cmd.

For example:

```
import sys
server = sys.argv[1]
database = sys.argv[2]
username = sys.argv[3]
password = sys.argv[4] 
print(server+database+username+password)
```

[image]

Correspondingly, you can modify your code:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import sys
server = sys.argv[1]
database = sys.argv[2]
username = sys.argv[3]
password = sys.argv[4] 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
# select 26 rows from SQL table to insert in dataframe.
query = "SELECT [CountryRegionCode], [Name] FROM Person.CountryRegion;"
df = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)
print(df.head(26))
```

Then manually enter the parameters when running the python file.